# Access VBA - Can I assign an instance of a form to a Subform control?

Tags: oop, object, ms-access, vba

Let's say I have a `MainForm` in Access.

On that `MainForm` is a `SubForm` control.

I also have another form called `AnotherForm` that I want to plug into the `MainForm`'s `SubForm` control using it's `SourceObject` property.

I then want to capture the instance of the newly created `AnotherForm` in a variable.

I can do that like this:

```
'Inside the MainForm's code-behind
Me.SubForm.SourceObject = "Form.AnotherForm" 

Dim af As Form_AnotherForm 

Set af = Me.SubForm.Form
```

Cool, `af` now holds the instance of the form created by the `SubForm` control when I set it's `SourceObject` property.

Now, instead, let's say I want to reverse that process by first `new`ing up an instance of `AnotherForm` and then passing it to the `SubForm` control.

Theoretically it would look something like this:

```
'Inside the MainForm's code-behind
Dim af As Form_AnotherForm

Set af = New Form_AnotherForm

Me.SubForm.Form = af  'ERROR: Read-only
```

Any way to accomplish that using some other method?

I want to be able to attach different forms to the `SubForm` control and switch them out at run-time. However, if I attach `AnotherForm` to `SubForm`, then attach `YetAnotherForm` to `SubForm`, then I go back and attach `AnotherForm` to `SubForm` again, I want to use the same instance of `AnotherForm` as I used the first time so that any changes on it won't be lost when it reappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, it's impossible. You cannot replace instance of subform, you can only change SourceObject, this operation destroys previous instance of subform and creates new one "from scratch".

I would use in your case tab control for holding instances of all subforms you want to switch between: create tab control with tabs style `none`, make borders transparent, so the appearance of subforms will be the same, as if one subform control used.

For switching between visible subforms just assign required value to tab conrol

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the Set statement:

```
Set Me.SubForm.Form = af
```